# Dax query - Running Total%

Tags: powerbi

I have request counts and trying to get running total % (in line graph) over stacked column chart. I have TAT defined in one of the column, for eg. >8 Hrs, 8-16 hrs, 16-24 hrs, 24-36 hrs, 36-48 hrs and greather 48 hourse.

```
On shred axis - TAT
Column value - request count
line - running total%
```

but sequence appearing on graph like this-

"16-24 hrs" "8-16 hrs" "<8 hrs" "24-36 hrs" ..so on..

```
TAT-Rank Table
<8 hrs - 1
8-16 hrs - 2
16-24 hrs - 3
24-36 hrs - 4
.. and till >48 hrs - 6
```

how do i get in proper sequence

none

````
```Running Total% = 
    DIVIDE(
        CALCULATE(
        COUNT('power bi test'[Service Request ID])
,FILTER(ALLEXCEPT('power bi test','power bi test'[Region Name],'power bi test'[Center Name],'power bi test'[Cert type for TAT]),'power bi test'[Rank]<=MAX('power bi test'[Rank]))
)
,
CALCULATE(
    COUNT('power bi test'[Service Request ID]),ALLEXCEPT('power bi test','power bi test'[Region Name],'power bi test'[Center Name],'power bi test'[Cert type for TAT])
    ) 
)
````

Answer (score 0):

What if you add Rank in tooltips and order by rank from the visual though it shows in Tooltip if enabled.

[image]